# JMeter + Gradle + Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am creating some performance tests for my project with JMeter running the profiles with Gradle and show them on Jenkins after build. All is good but this is not working if I try to use UltimateThreadGroup plugin for JMeter. Gradle doesn't know about this and same Jenkins.

Is there any way I can use UltimateThreadGroup on Gradle at least ?

If not, how can I automate some tests on JMeter (without a building tool) so I can run plain JMeter + UltimateThreadGroup plugin ? And from here I will extract my results and display them (not on Jenkins).

Thanks!